# Is it possible that we can post's a message own wall and set to privacy to view/like/comment for unfriend user(specfic user) by Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible that we can post's a message own wall and set to privacy to view/like/comment for unfriend user(specfic user) by Facebook API. Please suggest

Comment: No, you can't set the privacy for a specific person.

Comment: No prob man, glad I could help ;)

Comment: @User8889 How do you have 1k rep and no username? :P

Comment: I like being User8889 ;)